# Custom attribute not saving correctly in staging environment

Tags: magento2

I developed a Magento2 extension that enables adding product attributes of a custom type. When I save such custom attribute on my local machine, the script writes “frontend_input_renderer” property of the attribute to the database as expected ('catalog_eav_atttribute' table). When I do it on staging, it just adds a table row without this property in it (it writes null).

Local machine runs MAMP with php 7.0.0 and mysql 5.6.25.

Staging server runs Centos7 with php 7.0.7 and php-fpm, MariaDB 10.1.14, and SElinux.

What could cause different script execution in these two environments?

Comment: I am currently having the same problem! Did you have any tips for this problem, after all of this time? :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, that was so long ago l don't remember if I even resolved this. Magento CE codebase has been changing since then too. I gave up Magento development and only advice I can give you is try not to undertake any M2 projects - every dollar earned with magento goes straight to your therapist anyways.